# How can I change full name in dictionary to initial?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already have a dictionary

```
d1 = {'James Williams': 123, 'Adrian Falkenheim': 345}
```

How can I get `d2` as below ?

```
d2 = {'JW':123, "AF':345}
```

I already use for loop and split getting initial, but I do not know how to replace

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including the actual output and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
d2 = {
    ''.join(word[0] for word in key.split()): value
    for key, value in d1.items()
}
```

Or if you want to do it step by step:

```py
for key, value in d1.items():
    name = ''
    for word in key.split():
        name += word[0]
    d2.update({name: value})
```

Comment: Thx It really works!!! But as I am a beginner with python, can I ask if I do not use .join, how can I do it step by step? My thinking is getting the initial first:                                for name in d1.keys():
    full_name = name.split(' ')
    first_name = full_name[0]
    last_name = full_name[1]
    initial = [first_name[0] +last_name[0]]

Comment: Answer updated with second method, step by step